# Clustering words with similar meanings

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, text-mining

What methods are there to cluster words/word phrases with similar meanings together from a list of words/word phrases?

Answer (score 2):

At least one approach to this question would be to create word embeddings, apply PCA, and then use TSNE or K-means to cluster words with similar meanings.
Word embeddings can be created using [Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec#:%7E:text=Word2vec%20is%20a%20group%20of,reconstruct%20linguistic%20contexts%20of%20words.) or [GloVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloVe).

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
```

...

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(corpus, size=100, window=20, min_count=2, workers=16)
    keys = ["markets", "exchanges", "otc","stocks", "equity","indices", "ipo","commodity", "mortgages", "abs", "derivatives"]
    embedding_clusters = []
    word_clusters = []
    for word in keys:
        embeddings = []
        words = []
        for similar_word, _ in model.wv.most_similar(word, topn=15):
            words.append(similar_word)
            embeddings.append(model.wv[similar_word])
        embedding_clusters.append(embeddings)
        word_clusters.append(words)
```

...

```
embedding_clusters = np.array(embedding_clusters)
n, m, k = embedding_clusters.shape
tsne_model_en_2d = TSNE(perplexity=20, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=3500, random_state=42)
embeddings_en_2d = np.array(tsne_model_en_2d.fit_transform(embedding_clusters.reshape(n * m, k))).reshape(n, m, 2)


def tsne_plot_similar_words(title, labels, embedding_clusters, word_clusters, alpha, filename=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
    colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(labels)))
    for label, embeddings, words, color in zip(labels, embedding_clusters, word_clusters, colors):
        x = embeddings[:, 0]
        y = embeddings[:, 1]
        plt.scatter(x, y, color=color, alpha=alpha, label=label)
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            plt.annotate(word, alpha=0.5, xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(5, 2),
                         textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom', size=8)
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(True)
    if filename:
        plt.savefig(filename, format='png', dpi=150, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()


tsne_plot_similar_words('Similar words', keys, embeddings_en_2d, word_clusters, 0.7,
                        'other words.png')
```

[image]